# .NET Directory.Exists denies existence of mapped network drive when running as admin

Tags: .net, windows-7, uac

I'm writing a small .NET program on Windows 7.  One thing it needs to do is to create symbolic links, which seems to require me to have administrator privileges.  It also needs to be able to work with mapped network drives (for example, R:\, which on my system maps to `\\titanium\Private\`).

I'm using `Directory.Exists(path)` to verify that a path exists.

When running the program as a regular user (administrator account, but not "as administrator"), this works fine on the mapped network drive.

When running the program as an administrator (with UAC), it fails to find directories that exist.  As a result, the program refuses to acknowledge that `R:\Steam Games\` is a directory that actually exists.

I'm a bit baffled as to why this is happening.  Using the full UNC path (`\\titanium\Private\Steam Games\`) also doesn't work.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is there any good workaround?  Do I have to format the paths different (note:  most of them are currently formatted with `Path.Combine`, so they *should* be correct).

Thanks for your help.

(As an example, `Directory.Exists(@"R:\Steam Games\")` returns false when running as an admin, but that folder exists.  The function call correctly returns true when running regularly).

Edit:  The issue indeed appears to be that an administrator is technically a different user account.  I could not even use UNC paths, because I was only logged in to my fileserver under my regular user, not under "Administrator".  As a (relatively hackish) workaround, I just run my program with regular privileges and then use `Process.Start` to invoke an instance of cmd.exe with the arguments to create a symbolic link (and verb "runas" to get the UAC prompt).

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. The problem here is UAC (and that the UAC user is not in the same session as the non-UAC-user), and it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I think this is very on topic, as a programmer you need to be away of issues that happen if a end user decides to elevate your program.

Comment: I agree with Scott. It is a common programming problem and in my opinion this is a great site for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mapped drives in windows are tied to a user context. A drive mapped to a account: UserA, will not be accessible to UserB. You could create the same unc path mapped to the same drive letter under different users though.

Using the full unc path should work though.

More info at support.microsoft.com: [1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019185), [2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624).

Comment: The full UNC paths don't seem to work either.  I suspect that somehow my login to the network share is tied to just my user, so that if I try to access the same share as, say, "Administrator", it will expect me to reauthorize myself.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Whatever user the application is running under needs permission to the unc path. If you can access the path when logged in as that user, than the application should be able to access the same path programmatically through Directory.Exists...

Comment: You're using an administrator account, but is this a local administrator account? Does this administrator account have access to the remote path? Could you verify that?

Comment: I just tried this in PowerShell started as an administrator:  `cd \\titanium\Private\`, but it didn't work ("does not exist").  Why would this be?  How can I work around it?  I suppose I could write a separate program that makes the symbolic links and have my program simply run that one as an administrator "on-demand", but it seems like an awful lot of work for such a simple task.

Comment: I believe that within command line windows (and bat/cmd scripts), you can't directly reference unc paths. You must use mapped drives. I'll get back to you in a few minutes. Gonna boot up my windows machine and check.

Comment: That's why I used PowerShell - PowerShell supports UNC paths (I've used them before, just not as administrator).

Comment: You definitely cannot use UNC path in command line. There's no reason that Directory.Exists doesn't work for you other than it being a permission issue. You need to ensure that the user that you're running the application under has access to the directory your trying to access. That or you need to impersonate a user that does have access to the directory.

Comment: Command Prompt (cmd.exe) supports UNC path but with limitations. You cannot have a UNC path as current directory, yet you can copy a file from UNC path to local drive.

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. The non-elevated user has access to the network drive. The same user with administrator token enabled should also have access to the network drive, and mapped drives should also be visible. But if you enter another username/password when elevating, then the points above are false: another user has other permissions and can be denied to access network path, and there is not mapped drive R: or it can be tied to another network path.

Answer (score 2):

The basic reason why it does not work is that IIS user does not have permission to access the path. When running as regular user the access is given to the user i.e to make it work you need to give permission to the folder for IIS 
Follow as below for UNC path to work in services run by iis:

> Properties --> Security --> Edit--> Add --> IIS_WPG

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1344499.aspx). Apparently, in earlier versions of the .Net Framework [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) explicitly mentioned that this is not possible ("The Exists method does not perform network authentication. If you query an existing network share without being pre-authenticated, the Exists method will return false.").  The 4.0 documentation no longer contains this sentence, but the behavior has not changed.

I found a workaround [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/2933c233-2fe3-4b75-9949-84c56d539936) (but decided against using it).